# How to estimate a distribution from samples in a histogram

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, sampling, monte-carlo

Given a r.v. $\tau$ , I've computed $\Bbb{P}(\tau >a)=e^{-Nx}(e^{Nxe^{-a}}-1) $ , where $N\in\Bbb{N}_{>1}  $ and $ x\in \Bbb{R}_{>0} $ are just fixed parameters; say $N = 2 $ and $ x = 1$, for simplicity.

Now, I've been asked to make an histogram (say in Matlab) with samples of this r.v. , in order to check if this computation is correct...

How can I do this? How can I work out the distribution of a r.v. from a histogram?

Thank you

Comment: "How can I work out the distribution of a r.v. from a histogram?" Actually you mean exactly the opposite: "histogram from distribution" or not?

Comment: Maybe my English is betraying me, but I think I mean what I wrote:
$\tau$ is the waiting time of the first spike of a Neuronal Network, which has certain dyinamics involving non-homogeneous Poisson Processes. 

We are not sure that our computation of $\Bbb{P}(\tau>a) $ is correct, so I was asked to make a historgram in order to verify this. 

What is for sure is that we want to use a histogram in order to help us check if our computation is right, knowing the dynamics that determines the behaviour of $\tau$

Comment: The easiest, quickest and most precise thing would be to find $f_{\tau}(a)=-\frac d{da}P(\tau>a)$ and plot it.

Comment: And then compare it with the histogram?

Comment: Well, to produce a histogram (approximation of $f_{\tau}$) you'll have to sample $\tau$. Your question is unclear - what are you going to compare the histogram/density with? Can you visually deduce whether you obtained the correct result? Actually - you definitely got a wrong answer, since $P(\tau>a)<0$

Comment: I thought about comparing the histogram, with the plot of $ f_{\tau}$ to check (obviuslyy, in an informal way) that the computation I've made for $ \Bbb{P}(\tau > a )$ is correct, at least broadly speaking. 
If the actual samplings of $\tau$ don't agree with the plot of $ f_{\tau}$ then I must have made a mistake when computing. 

Am I making a conceptual mistake?

Comment: Yes, you are. First of all, your $P(\tau>a)$ is negative, so its incorrect. Second of all, comparing sampling histogram with $f_{\tau}$ could only validate your *sampling method* - not ccdf $P(\tau>a)$.

Comment: About the first point, you're right. I meant  $\Bbb{P}(\tau >a)=e^{-Nx}(e^{Nxe^{-a}}-1) $ 

About the second, I'll have to meditate on the matter. So  what would you do, in order to compare what I mean to?

Comment: 1. Your choice of $\bar F_{\tau}$ allows for negative $\tau$. Is that your intention? 2. I simply don't know what your intentions are. Try to express what exactly you are trying to achieve.